# Can't fill ComboBox option

Tags: php, mysql

```
$i = 1;
$tbl = "";
$field = "";

if($_POST['jenis']=="Bahan Baku")
{
   $tbl = "bahanbaku";
   $field = "bb_";
}
else if($_POST['jenis']=="Bahan Penunjang")
{
   $tbl = "bahanpenunjang";
   $field = "bp_";
}

<select class="span10" name="jenis" class="add-on">
   <?php
    $opt = "SELECT bb_nama FROM ".$tbl."";
    $result = mysql_query($opt);
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<option>". $row[$field.'nama'] ."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

The result is none of the selected rows displayed. which line is wrong?

Comment: Is your query working, and returning results? Bear in mind that with your current code, you'll only ever return a single line.

Comment: Also - your first part of code (before <select> field) is not wrapped with <?php ?> tags

Comment: The syntax errors don't help... `... FROM ".$tbl."";`. That doubled quote at the end is going to kill your script.

Comment: the php b4 <select> is declaration that i made on top of page.. so ofc i wrapped it up in php tags.. the only error i get is inside the <select> tag, it wont show up my query.. i tried echo $opt; but the query still doesnt show up..

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<option>". $row[$field.'nama'] ."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

for

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

in order to iterate over the entire resultset

Answer (score 0):

$opt = "SELECT **bb_nama** FROM ".$tbl."";

you are selecting the field bb_nama, but when you retrieving time you are doing $row[$field.'nama']. the field is mismatch while the table value is changing.

in other case, query should be

$opt = "SELECT ".$field."_nama FROM ".$tbl."";

Comment: oh sry i forgot to change that line.. but i tried it b4 and still the same error..